# NAME is not defined when defining class arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I am having an issue I have not had before creating a class with a method as below;

```
class Points:

def __init__(self, inFC, buffDist, sector): #Must have a set of points and a value to buffer these by. Also, sector.

    self.inFC = inFC
    self.buffDist = buffDist
    self.sector = sector

def getCoords(self): #getting the coordinates of the points.

    fc = self.inFC
    fields = ['SHAPE@XY']

    coordsList = []

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as rows:
        coordsList = [r[0] for r in rows]
    self.coordsList = coordsList
    del coordsList
```

The class is created and the method called from this code at the end of my script;

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

inFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
buffDist = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
sector = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
outFC_data = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

fcName = outFC_data.rpartition("\\")[2]
fcPath = outFC_data.rpartition("\\")[0]
outFC = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(fcPath, fcName, "POLYGON")

pointobject = Points(inFC, buffDist, sector)
pointobject.getCoords()
```

This returns the error "fc is not defined" at the line fc = self.inFC.

OR

if I remove "fc = self.InFC" and replace fc with self.inFC within SearchCursor then I get an error at the line "with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(self.inFC, fields)" that states "self.inFC is not defined".

I have tried pasting the class definition directly into the python interpreter (ArcCatalog->Geoprocessing->Python) but the errors remain the same, so I do not even get to the point of creating an instance of the class, the error is within the actual code of my class and method definition.

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: Just to check: Is your indentation correct, just pasted wrong in here?

Comment: If you include an `if arcpy.exists(inFC): print "it exists"` check somewhere before working on `pointobject`, what is the result? The problem may be the initial inputs that it's getting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your input parameter. Since I'm guessing that you're doing your debugging in ArcMap (don't do that btw, use PyScripter, PyCharm or at least IDLE) you can use arcpy.AddMessage(*string*) to view the value of that parameter in the geoprocessing results messages, which in the case of a feature class should look like a file path. I'd stick one of these before initializing the class, and once right before the point of failure as well. Let me know what happens!